# How to create double fullpage spreads in a two-column environment

Tags: floats, two-column, alignment, double-sided

To create a double-page spread, in which an image is spread across two pages of an open book, with no white space (no margins, headers, and footers), the package `hvfloat` is recommended.

This package, however, does not seem to be working for me in a two-column book.  If the figure is placed after the last page of a chapter, whose left column is longer than the right column, then the left side of the figure is near the middle of the page, rather than flush with the left side of the page, as the documentation promises.

Inserting `\clearpage` before the float fails to solve the problem, and creates more problems with columns and caption in the following chapter (not shown).

The `hvfloat` syntax is copied exactly from the `hvfloat` example document `doublepage2s2c.tex`.

Minimum working example below.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage[letterpaper,
bindingoffset=5mm,
left=16mm,
right=16mm,
top=20mm,
bottom=20mm,
footskip=5mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\chapter{1}
\lipsum[1-5]


\hvFloat[doubleFULLPAGE,capWidth=n,twoColumnCaption,capPos=after,separatorLine]%
{figure}%
{\includegraphics[doubleFULLPAGE]{example-image-b}}%
[A doublepage image with a caption on the page following.]%
{A caption for a double-sided image that will be placed on the bottom of the page after the right side of the image. The illustration begins on the left edge of the paper. A short form is used for the LOF. The parameter is \texttt{doubleFULLPAGE}}%
{fig:doubleFULLPAGE0after2col}

\chapter{2}

\lipsum[1-5]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!! If the answer meets your requirement, please accept it by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer.

Comment: @SimonDispa thank you for your answer!  Although the problem is solved in the MWE, it remains in the actual document. I will troubleshoot and edit the original question adding a new MWE if it remains unresolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `geometry` settings to:

```
\usepackage[letterpaper, 
left=21mm,%16mm +5mm
right=16mm, 
top=20mm,
bottom=20mm,
includefoot,% 
showframe % optional, show the margins
]{geometry}
```

and place `\hvFloat` before the text so that it stays within the chapter. Also add `bindCorr=5mm` to the float.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage[letterpaper, 
left=21mm,%16mm +5mm
right=16mm, 
top=20mm,
bottom=20mm,
includefoot,% 
showframe
]{geometry}


\usepackage{hvfloat}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \twocolumn
    \chapter{1}

    \hvFloat[doubleFULLPAGE,capWidth=n,twoColumnCaption,capPos=after,separatorLine, bindCorr=5mm]% here <<<<
    {figure}%
    {\includegraphics[doubleFULLPAGE]{example-image-b}}%
    [A doublepage image with a caption on the page following.]%
    {A caption for a double-sided image that will be placed on the bottom of the page after the right side of the image. The illustration begins on the left edge of the paper. A short form is used for the LOF. The parameter is \texttt{doubleFULLPAGE}}%
    {fig:doubleFULLPAGE0after2col}
    
    \lipsum[1-5] 
        
    \chapter{2}
    
    \lipsum[1-5]
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image: c]

In a real document you can use the option `nonFloat=true` to insert the float close to the desired place. For example:

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage[letterpaper, 
left=21mm,%16mm +5mm
right=16mm, 
top=20mm,
bottom=20mm,
includefoot,% 
showframe % optional, show the margins
]{geometry}


\usepackage{hvfloat}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \twocolumn
    \chapter{1}
    
    \lipsum[1] 

    \hvFloat[doubleFULLPAGE,capWidth=n,twoColumnCaption,capPos=after,separatorLine, bindCorr=5mm, nonFloat=true]% here <<<<
    {figure}%
    {\includegraphics[doubleFULLPAGE]{example-image-b}}%
    [A doublepage image with a caption on the page following.]%
    {A caption for a double-sided image that will be placed on the bottom of the page after the right side of the image. The illustration begins on the left edge of the paper. A short form is used for the LOF. The parameter is \texttt{doubleFULLPAGE}}%
    {fig:doubleFULLPAGE0after2col}
    
    \lipsum[2-5] 
        
    \chapter{2}
    
    \lipsum[1-5]
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: For your MWE directly above I do not get the same pdflatex compiled result.  I don't think I can post images in a comment, so I'll describe: my pages 1 and 2 are identical to yours. My page 3 has text overlain on the figure, on the upper right side. That text is the same as yours on page four. My page four has no document text, and just the caption in the middle of the page with separator line. My pages 5 and 6 are identical to yours.  I copied your MWE directly in a separate .tex file in TexStudio and compiled with pdflatex.

Comment: @Sowberry Hagan I added the complete code.

Comment: I get the same compilation regardless of whether nonFloat is true or not: the additional text that does not fit on the page immediately before the float is printed over the right half of the image, on the upper right corner.  And, the following page is empty except for the caption in the middle of the page.  The remaining two pages are identical.  I copied your example code verbatim into a new .text file in TexStudio and compiled with pdflatex.

Comment: @Sowberry Hagan I am using This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.10;  LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5 ; Package: hvfloat 2022/10/02 v2.42 special floating objects (hv)

Comment: @Sowberry Hagan Try removing the geometry package.  You are right:  nonFloat  is irrelevant here. No difference using  hvfloat 2023/05/16 v2.46

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.8.16)

hvfloat 2021/09/23 v2.34 special floating objects (hv)

Aha, looks like my default-loaded hvfloat is old. I'll update it to the latest.

Comment: @@Sowberry Hagan Download the full package from CTAN and put hvfloat.sty in your working directory.

Comment: Package: hvfloat 2023/05/16 v2.46 special floating objects (hv) 
Done, now working exactly as in your example!